# How to refresh parent page form a child page in javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a way to refresh the parent page from a page it was originated from.

For example I have a parent.php page where I have JavaScript function which opens a child.php from it using JavaScript:

PARENT.PHP

```
  <input type="submit"  value="new Page" onclick="createChild()" >

  <script>
  function createChild()
   {
       myWindow = open('child.php', '', 'menubar=no, width=450, height=550');
  }
  </script>
```

In the child page I want to have a javascript function which will refresh a parennt.php but somehow it is not working.

CHILD.PHP

```
   <script>
   function refreshHOme()
   {
      myWindow.window.location.href = myWindow.window.location;
   }
   </script>
```

When I click refresh Home button nothing happens. Does anyone know if it's possible and if yes what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `window.opener.location.reload();` try this

Comment: Thank YOu MKA. it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent window object by using `window.opener` or opener.

To refresh the parent window, try the following:

```
funcion refreshHOme() {
    opener.location.reload();
        or 
    opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.open(myWindow.window.location);
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

on Child use

```
 window.opener.location.href = your location
```